# difference between makefile target names

Tags: makefile

Running `make` twice on this target:

```
hello: 
       gcc hello.c hello_test.c -o hello
```

gives the massage `make: hello is up to date.`, as expected.
However, running `make` multiple times on this target:

```
hello1: 
       gcc hello.c hello_test.c -o hello
```

creates the executable file again and again, without the above message.
What's the reason?

Comment: How do you think Make knows to not re-run on the first example?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, it checks whether `hello` existed and if there were any changes on `hello.c` and `hello_test.c`, to my understanding.

Comment: Exactly - and it does that because it knows to look for a thing called `hello`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @OliverCharlesworth commented, the first rule makes it possible for Make to look for a thing called `hello` (which is the name of both the target and the executable) and determine whether it needs to be updated. 
The second rule, however, gives different names to the target and the executable, so Make can't know that the target it up to date.